# Make the first line small caps

Tags: formatting, automation

I am transferring certain hand-taken notes to digital in two-column format, and I put a divider between the notes. For an extra visual cue, I want to make the first line of a new note to be in small caps. Something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\newcommand\divider{%
    \begin{center}
        \pgfornament[width=8pt, color=darkgray]{6}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\firstlinesc\blindtext[1]

\divider

\firstlinesc\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

What are my options?